# Why BigDecimal.ZERO is unscaled?

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal, zero

The Javadoc for `BigDecimal.ZERO` says `The value 0, with a scale of 0.` As the name suggests one may expect that `BigDecimal.ZERO` should return value `0.0`

I also know that it is the way `BigDecimal.ZERO` is coded:

```
private static final BigDecimal zeroThroughTen[] = {
        new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO,         0,  0, 1),
        new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE,          1,  0, 1),
...
}

// Constants
/**
 * The value 0, with a scale of 0.
 *
 * @since  1.5
 */
public static final BigDecimal ZERO =
        zeroThroughTen[0];
```

I don't understand why it is decided in Java that `BigDecimal.ZERO` returns unscaled zero rather than return decimal zero (at least with scale 1 by default, i.e. `0.0`).

What is the need that `BigDecimal.ZERO` and `BigInteger.ZERO` both returns value `0` with scale `0`?

Comment: Why should it be `0.0` instead of `0` or `0.00`? `0.0` sounds like a rather arbitrary choice. Zero is zero, so just `0` (with scale 0) sounds like a reasonable default.

Comment: You are correct zero is zero, then why 2 constants defines 0

Comment: Because `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` are not just numbers, they are special classes that can be used to store numbers, and the constants define a `BigDecimal` with the value zero and a `BigInteger` with the value zero.

Comment: Why are you asking?  Frankly, it makes no difference whether you or anyone thinks the current definition is incorrect.  The definition is what it is.  The backward compatibility imperative means that it **won't be changed**.

Comment: Asking just to get clarified, was curious about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know why you think `BigDecimal.ZERO` should be `0.0`. Why not `0.00` or `0.000`?

The advantage of defining `BigDecimal.ZERO` with scale 0 is that it is up to the developer to set the scale that is needed. For example you can always construct a BigDecimal of value 0 with a different scale:

```
BigDecimal zero = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2);
```

Scale 0 provides a good default value and adheres with the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Let's admit for a second that `BigDecimal.ZERO` was defined as `0.0`. Consider the following code:

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("20");
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("20").add(BigDecimal.ZERO);
System.out.println(b.equals(b2)); // false ??? since when 20 != 20 + 0 ??
```

`b` and `b2` would not be equal (as per [`BigDecimal.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)) because they would have different scale: `b` would have a scale of 0 and `b2` would have a scale of 1 (because [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-) returns a `BigDecimal` whose scale is the max of the two `BigDecimal`s scale).

Comment: I agree that I think it should be 0.0